# algorithm to search to check for string match

Tags: c, string

I have two strings `a`,`b` of equal length `l1`, `l2` respectively. I want to return the number of common letters for the given two strings. For example, `a='ABC'` and `b='CDE'`. My algorithm should return `1` because only `'C'` is the common letter in both the strings, but it returns `26` instead. Could anyone please explain why? This is my algorithm:

```
for(i=0; i < l1; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j < l2; j++)
    {
        if(a[i] == b[j])
        {
            found++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: found is declared as int type

Comment: ...and set to zero, too?

Comment: Equal length? why l1 and l2 then?

Comment: Please take the time to read about what constitutes a [MCVE].

Comment: Post complete runnable code. Nothing in your code explains 26.

Comment: Your requirement needs to be clarified. If one string is "ABCC" and the other is "CFGC", should the count be 1 or 2?

Comment: @FredK  For "ABCC" and CFGC" it should be `2`. But for "A" and "AAAA" it should be `1`. The algorithm wrongly gives `4`.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm would fail your criteria. It's easy to see what would happen if a string was 'CCC'.

Do like this:

```
int letters[26]={0};
int both[26]={0};

for(int i=0; i<l1; i++)
   letters[a[i]-'A']=1;

for(int i=0; i<l2; i++)
    if(letters[b[i]-'A'])
        both[b[i]-'A']=1;

int found=0;

for(int i=0; i<26; i++)
    found+=both[i];
```

Comment: You can get rid of `for(int i=0; i<26; i++)
    letters[i]=0;` and do `int letters[26] = {0};`

Comment: Thanks. Also fixed a bug.

Comment: What about small letters and punctuation characters? E.g.  `letters= "Is it really working?"` and  `both = "Maybe not!"`

Answer (score 0):

```
// With this code I preferred to convert all char as an ascii code.
// Because it is more simpler to compare int value than with `2` for statement 
// it has compared if chars are similar, increase the number of `sayi`, then 
// print the equal char of these code

int main(){
    char a[]="ABC";
    char b[]="CDE";
    int sizeofa=sizeof(a)-1;
    int sizeofb=sizeof(b)-1;
    int sayi=0;
    int asciia;
    int asciib;

    for (int i=0; i<sizeofa;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<sizeofb; j++)
        {
            asciia=a[i];
            asciib=b[j];

            if ( asciia == asciib)
                sayi++;
        }

    }
    printf("%d",sayi);
}
```

Comment: `sizeof stringarray - 1` is usually written as `strlen(stringarray)` (the compiler will (hopefully) optimize to the same constant).

Comment: I tried out the same code  in the following manner but I am getting the output as 26 instead of 4.

Comment: when I tried this code gave me 1.probably the problem is in the converting to ascii.

Answer (score 0):

The example is incomplete, so it is difficult to tell why you get `26`. Possibly `found` has not been initialized or your printout is not correct.

The algorithm itself is not correct since it would over-count common characters.
For example for

```
char *a = "A";
char *b = "AAAA";
```

The second loop would count `'A'` character `4` times.

```
for(j=0;j<l2;j++)
{
    if(a[i]==b[j])
```

You have to avoid over-counting, for example take a look at :

```
size_t count_common_chars(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    size_t counter = 0;   // our occurrence counter
    int index[256] = {0}; // clear the index table

    while(*s1){           // for every character in the string s1
        index[*s1]++;     // use string s1 characters as index to index table  s1 = "aaa" would yield index['a'] == 3 
        s1++;             // advance to next char
    }

    // For every character in the string s2 check if character existed in s1.
    // If yes increase the counter. 
    // 
    // If a particular character occurs 'n' times in string s1
    // then the number of common characters in string s2 cannot be greater than 'n'. 
    // That is why we have to subtract the number of occurrences of a given character 'X' in string s2
    // from the reference index table which counted the occurrence of the same character in string s1.
    //
    // This is a generic approach, we would do subtraction whether or not there is a match.
    // At the end the index table contains a count of a differences between s1 and s2.
    // Positive number at the specific index means that there was more such characters in string s1 
    // Negative number at the specific index means that there was more such characters in string s2
    // 0 means that number of particular character was the same or there was no such character in the strings s1 and s2

    while(*s2){            // for every character in the string s2
        if ( (index[*s2]--)  >  0)  
            counter++;
        s2++;
    }            
    return counter;
}
```